# HTML5 Video Player Issue PHP

Tags: codeigniter, html5-video, codeigniter-3

I am getting an problem when loading a URL in HTML5 Player.
When I am playing the video using the physical path of the video like `http://localhost/udemy/assets/images/videos/V20200724142619.mp4` it is working fine.

But when I am trying to load the video using the function like
`http://localhost/udemy/web/fetch_video/7`

The video is loading and playing perfect but seeking is not working

my php code is

```
function fetch_video($video)
{
    $modify=$this->data->get_modify_data('chapter','id',$video);
    $file = $modify['video'];
    $ext=explode('.',$file);
    $type=$ext[count($ext)-1];
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $file_pointer = fopen($file, "rb");
    $data = fread($file_pointer, $file_size);
    header("Content-type: video/$type");
    echo $data;
}
```

Comment: `but seeking is not working` means?

Comment: Like youtube we can play the video after 30 minutes we can seek video after an hour on progress bar click but it is not working in HTML5 video player while giving video URL through a function

Comment: if your local video encoded with the MOOV atom at the start (to provide the metadata quickly so the browser knows where frames are), and does your server support byte range requests that allow the browser to request specific parts of the file rather than wait for the whole thing to be loaded?

Comment: DId you look at the difference between the response headers of the two methods? That might give you a clue as to which header is missing...